# What is the inverse of $f(x) = \sqrt{x} + 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got

$$f^{-1}(x) = (x-2)^2$$

Is this answer right?

Comment: yes it is right

Comment: Take notice of the fact that it is true if $f:\left[0,\infty\right)\rightarrow\left[2,\infty\right)$ and $f^{-1}:\left[2,\infty\right)\rightarrow\left[0,\infty\right)$. The domain of $f$ must be the codomain of $f^{-1}$ and the codomain of $f$ must be the domain of $f^{-1}$. Domain and codomain are essential parts of the function, which is (too) often neglected.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your answer is correct. For future users:

\begin{align}
y &= \sqrt{x} + 2 \\
x &= \sqrt{y} + 2 \\
(x-2) &= \sqrt{y} \\
(x-2)^2 &= y
\end{align}

The idea is  to replace $x$ with $y$ and solve for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do mean $\sqrt{x}+2$ and not $\sqrt{x+2}$, the answer is correct, except that I'd add that the domain of $f^{-1}$ is $x\ge 2$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \geq 0$ you have $f(x) =y \geq 2$ and 
$$y= \sqrt{x}+2 \iff \sqrt{x}=y-2 \iff x=(y-2)^2=:f^{-1}(y).$$